# Storing audio file/file path in MySQL workbench using MySQL syntax

Tags: java, mysql, processing

I would like to ideally store a file path instead of the audio file directly into the database I have created for storing music metadata.

I am creating a music program in Processing (Java) which will access the contents of the database, compare the BPM (beats per minute) of all the songs and find a song with a very similar BPM to the song that's currently playing and then the program will play that new song (if that makes sense)

I am unable to find any statement in the MySQL syntax that allows me add a music file or file path to a column called 'track location'. I can only find statements in Java, C# and PHP.

Please also advise me if my method of retrieving and comparing data in the database is the best way to go about it. Essentially, I would like the program to simply compare the BPM's of each file in the user's existing music library and recommend/play a track with a similar BPM next.

Answer (score 0):

If you're storing file locations, then those are just string values.

You should be able to add a string to your table like this:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD track_location TEXT;
```

More info can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp).

Comment: I have done the following statement and it is not working. 

ALTER TABLE music ADD track_location '/Desktop/data/Soak It - Hyenah.mp3'
 WHERE ID = 1;

@Kevin Workman

Comment: @ZIqbal Please be more specific than saying it is not working. What exactly happens?

Comment: the error says 'please check the syntax'

I have tried putting the file path in brackets, without quotes etc but it's not working. I am unable to see on the documentation the correct syntax

Comment: @ZIqbal If you're having a specific syntax problem with SQL, that's a pretty different question than the one you've asked above, which is a more general Processing question. Consider splitting them up into their own posts.